# Downgrade SVN repository client

Tags: linux, svn

For some network speed reasons, I uploaded a .tar.gz copy of a checked out svn project on the server from a dev environment, but I ended with the version issues. The final server had lower version of subversion 1.6.11 while the source was at 1.7.14. Latest release of 1.7 is not yet available to install on the target.

I now cannot make use of this directly copy/pasted files.
svn 'upgrade' command is not available on the target.

Can I somehow now downgrade the checked out repository?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading from 1.7 to 1.6 is not possible. Please find accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862204/1495678).
 Why downgrading is not possible can be found in [script](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/change-svn-wc-format.py) used to downgrade . (Line 277)

> ## Maps format numbers to indices of fields within an entry's record that must
>
> # be retained when downgrading to that format.

```
must_retain_fields = {
      # Not in 1.4: changelist, keep-local, depth, tree-conflicts, file-externals
      8  : (30, 31, 33, 34, 35),
      # Not in 1.5: tree-conflicts, file-externals
      9  : (34, 35),
      10 : (),



 # Downgrading from format 11 (1.7-dev) to format 10 is not possible,
  # because 11 does not use has-props and cachable-props (but 10 does).
  # Naively downgrading in that situation causes properties to disappear
  # from the wc.
  #
  # Downgrading from the 1.7 SQLite-based format to format 10 is not
  # implemented.
  }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.